# Obtaining a null pointer exception on hashmap.get() method

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, javabeans

I seem to be recieving a nullpointer exception when i place a property inside the .get() method when i call the entiire collection it prints what i want here is the code. if anybody can help it would be much appreciated im new to stack overflow.

```
        session.setAttribute("AvailableLessons",availableLessons.getLessons()); will print out contents of the hashmaps. 

        session.setAttribute("AvailableLessons",availableLessons.getLessons(Lesson.description)); will return null pointer expcetion and the property is a db column name and when i step through it, will have a value in the property.
```

here is the rest of the code:

```
        private LessonTimetable availableLessons =  new LessonTimeTable();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("Username", username);
        response.sendRedirect("/coursework/LessonTimetableView.jspx");
        String printOut = ((String) session.getAttribute("Username"));
        out.print("You are logged in as " + printOut);
        session.setAttribute("AvailableLessons",availableLessons.getDescription());
```

here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
controller.Controller.processRequest(Controller.java:79)
controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:88)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: availibleLessons could be null, your description property could be null, its hard to know without the rest of the code.

Comment: the interesting this is avilableLessons will print out all the contents of the hashmap so i know its not null

Comment: once i specify the key it returns null

Comment: could you please share the stack trace

Comment: Sysout this value `availableLessons.getLessons(Lesson.description)` and see what you get. May be it's null.

Comment: it is null, but when i step through and get to my models they have the data from the db. only when i get to servlet level they are null

Comment: right i fixed this but how do i display the key at jstl level based on a string key not just the key and value property